# Dynamic creation of a button in QML

Tags: qt, components, qml, qtquickcontrols

With qt 5.2, I'm trying to add dynamically a simple button like this :

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: appWindow

    width: 640
    height: 420
    minimumHeight: 400
    minimumWidth: 600

    function addButton() {

        var obj = Qt.createComponent("Button.qml");

        if (obj.status == obj.Ready)
        {
            var button = obj.createObject(appWindow);
            button.color = "red";
            button.width=50;
            button.height=80;
            button.x=50; button.y=50;
           }
     }


    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        text: "ok";

        onClicked: {
            addButton();
        }
    } ...
```

But just after the createComponent I always get :

> QQmlComponent: Component is not ready

What's wrong ?

Comment: As per the example [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html). The `object.status` must be checked for equality(`==`) with `Component.Ready` enum. And also you can print, the errors like this

`if (component.status == Component.Error) {
   // Error Handling
   console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
 }`

I hope, the `addButton` function is not resolved in the static Button component. So try adding `appWindow.addButton();` in the `onClicked` event handler.

Comment: I've added import statement to the beginning of the file and it works correctly without errors. I see a button

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that the component will be ready, the best way is simply to declare it inside the QML part, inside a Component object, so that it'll be preloaded at same time as the rest of the file :

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow;

    Component {
        id: myButton;

        Button { }
    }

    function addButton () {
        var button = myButton.createObject (appWindow, {
                                                "color"  : "red",
                                                "width"  : 50,
                                                "height" : 80,
                                                "x"      : 50, 
                                                "y"      : 50
                                            });
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, I also took the liberty to show you the syntax to create the object directly with the good properties in one shot, instead of setting them manually in the old school way. Much more clean code and probably more performant.